# Log4j2 Rollover based on date but override based on size limit

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm trying to configure a RollingFile appender which performs a rollover after every month (for 18 months). However in addition, I want log4j2 to override my current log if it reaches 25 MB. For example, if we are currently in February, then I would have a previous log for January. However, if my current February log will reach 25 MB then my February log would be overwritten with a new log for February. This is my current appender configuration:

```
<RollingFile name="audit-log" fileName="${sys:user.dir}/${baseDir}/${projectName}-Audit.log" immediateFlush="true" filePattern="${sys:user.dir}/${baseDir}/${projectName}-Audit.%d{yyyy-MM}.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5level: %msg%n"/>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="25 MB"/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="18"/>
</RollingFile>
```

However this rolls over whether I have switched months or reached the 25 MB size limit. How can I make logs roll over only after switching months, but have my current log be overwritten after the size limit has been reached?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the following configuration:

```
<RollingFile name="audit-log" fileName="${sys:user.dir}/${baseDir}/${projectName}-Audit.log" immediateFlush="true" filePattern="${sys:user.dir}/${baseDir}/${projectName}-Audit.%d{yyyy-MM}.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5level: %msg%n"/>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="25 MB"/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1">
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}">
            <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="18" />
        </Delete>
    </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>
```